# Choose random index of array with condition on value

Tags: php, arrays, random, conditional-statements

I have an array of booleans, from which I want to pick a random index whose value is true and set it to false.

I can, of course, do this with brute force by picking indices until I hit one whose value is true:

```
$arr = array(true, false, false, true, false, true);

var_dump($arr);

$i = array_rand($arr);
while(!$arr[$i])
{
    $i = array_rand($arr);
}
$arr[$i] = false;

var_dump($arr);
```

This creates something like this, where the fourth entry got changed.

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  bool(true)
  [1]=>
  bool(false)
  [2]=>
  bool(false)
  [3]=>
  bool(true)
  [4]=>
  bool(false)
  [5]=>
  bool(true)
}

array(6) {
  [0]=>
  bool(true)
  [1]=>
  bool(false)
  [2]=>
  bool(false)
  [3]=>
  bool(false)
  [4]=>
  bool(false)
  [5]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

However, I have to do this operation several times with a significantly larger array. At some point the array is nearly completely false, in which case the brute force method is rather inefficient.

Is there any more elegant method of solving this problem? Any kind of `array_rand()` function, where I can give a precondition?

Comment: Are you planning to run this in a loop or something similar that would do each `true` entry at one point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = array(true,true,false,false,true,false);

$res = array_keys($arr, true);

var_dump($res);  // returns 0,1,4

echo $res[array_rand($res)]; //echo one of the indexes that is true
```

The above code returns the indexes of the true values of $arr in $res.

https://3v4l.org/CG1v2

Edit. To then set one of $arr indexes as false you should:

```
$arr[$res[array_rand($res)]] = false; // will set one as false.
```

Looping these two lines will eventually set all indexes to false:

```
$res = array_keys($arr, true);
$arr[$res[array_rand($res)]] = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
$arr = array(true, false, false, true, false, true);

$randTrueIndex = array_rand(array_filter($arr, function($item) { 
    return $item;
}));

$arr[$randTrueIndex] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this without wasting any work would be to create a random permutation of the array indices. The Knuth shuffle (also known as [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)) should work admirably.

Another option for certain applications would be picking a generator that creates values in the desired range without repetition, or with only a comparatively small number of outliers (values that fall outside the target range). For example, all [linear-congruential generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) have the property that any lower n bits cycle with period 2^n. Pick the first power of two that is not less than your array size and you'll generate less than one wasted number for every good one on average.

Comment: I thought about permutations. But since the array is not entirely true in the beginning, it seems that there is no way of pre-selecting the true indices first.
Thanks for mentioning the generators. I keep it in mind.

Comment: @Sebastian: In that case you could select the indices of the true entries into an array and shuffle that... I.e. basically what Ismail wrote.